# Adapt y-axis in Tikzpicture (bar-chart)

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I am trying to figure things out for over 2h now, but just do not get it. I need a bar chart and found a nice solution online on someones website. But for the life of me, I just can't figure out how to adapt the y-axis.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw (0,0) -- (11.5,0);  %Abzisse
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,-0.1);  %linkes Ende der Abzisse


  \draw (-0.1,0) -- (-0.1,8.5);  %Ordinate
  \draw (-0.1,0) -- (-0.2,0);  %unteres Ende der Ordinate


  \foreach \x in {5,10,15}  %Hilfslinien
    \draw[gray!50, text=black] (-0.2,\x) -- (11.5,\x) 
  node at (-0.5,\x) {\x};  %Beschriftung der Hilfslinien


  \foreach \x/\y/\anzahl in {0.3/3/16,  %\x ist Anfang der Säulen
                          1.3/8/17,  %\y ist Höhe der Säulen
                          2.3/3/18,
                          3.3/2/19,
                          4.3/2/20,
                          5.3/1/21,
                          6.3/1/22,
                         7.3/1/24,
                          8.3/2/31,
                          9.3/1/42,
                          10.3/1/43}
{
 \draw[fill=myblue] (\x cm,0cm) rectangle (0.6+\x ,\y ) %die Säulen
   node at (0.3 + \x ,\y + 0.3) {\y}; %die Prozente über den Säulen
 \node[rotate=0, left] at (0.85 +\x,-0.5) {\anzahl}; %Säulenbeschriftung
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Sonne} \label{fig:BD1}
\end{figure}
```

I want to adapt the y-axis. It still should create the lines with 5, 10 and 15 but not in cm, which makes the chart huge. Is there any way to tell latex to create the line 5 on the y-axis at 2 cm and therefore 10 at 5 cm and so on?

[image]

Comment: Please complete your code into a minimal working example. As it stands, your code is not compilable. It would be helpful to add a picture of the result you are expecting, or a picture demonstrating the problem you have..

Comment: Hi Troy, thank you for your post. What do you mean by "minimal working example"? I copied the code from another website and put it into my document. It worked, so I assumed this would be fine. I did not change a lot from the original, just my numbers and stuff.

Comment: A a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is a compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. For example, I've added the image to your post, but since there's no the definition of `myblue` in your code, I've changed it into `blue` in order to be able to produce the picture.

Comment: I'm assuming when you say 'adapt the y axis' you would want the bars to scale smaller vertically as well? Then would scaling the `tikzpicture` vertically be an acceptable solution? With `\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.5cm]`, for example. Thanks @CarLaTeX !

Comment: @Troy You're welcome! I think `[y=0.5cm]` is what the OP wants, also `\draw (-0.1,0) -- (-0.1,15);  %Ordinate` instead of `\draw (-0.1,0) -- (-0.1,8.5);  %Ordinate` is needed. Nadine, otherwise tell us what you want (because you can't have a line that shows 5 when your data are 2...).

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! Thank you! Thank you! THANK YOU!!! [y=0.5cm] did the trick. I would have never figured that out. You guys are so amazing an always so helpful. Again, thank you all so much!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

BTW, you might take a look at `pgfplots` (I would be very surprised is there wasn't a manual in Deutsch.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw (0,0) -- (11.5,0);  %Abzisse
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,-0.1);  %linkes Ende der Abzisse


  \draw (-0.1,0) -- (-0.1,8.5);  %Ordinate
  \draw (-0.1,0) -- (-0.2,0);  %unteres Ende der Ordinate


  \foreach \x in {2,4,6,8}  %Hilfslinien
    \draw[gray!50, text=black] (-0.2,\x) -- (11.5,\x) 
  node at (-0.5,\x) {\x};  %Beschriftung der Hilfslinien


  \foreach \x/\y/\anzahl in {0.3/3/16,  %\x ist Anfang der Säulen
                          1.3/8/17,  %\y ist Höhe der Säulen
                          2.3/3/18,
                          3.3/2/19,
                          4.3/2/20,
                          5.3/1/21,
                          6.3/1/22,
                         7.3/1/24,
                          8.3/2/31,
                          9.3/1/42,
                          10.3/1/43}
{
 \draw[fill=blue] (\x cm,0cm) rectangle (0.6+\x ,\y ) %die Säulen
   node at (0.3 + \x ,\y + 0.3) {\y}; %die Prozente über den Säulen
 \node[rotate=0, left] at (0.85 +\x,-0.5) {\anzahl}; %Säulenbeschriftung
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]